# How to do a faster paging over large data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012, paging

I've seen a lot of examples but none of them seem to help me enough.

Here are the ones I've implemented and working, but very slow:

Approach 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    LogVisits T (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    T.Msisdn = @TempMsisdn
ORDER BY 
    T.[VisitUrlCreatedDate], T.[VisitId] DESC
OFFSET @RecordStartIndex ROWS
FETCH NEXT (@RecordEndIndex - @RecordStartIndex) ROWS ONLY;
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT
    *
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vLogVisit) AS [TotalRecordCount]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.[VisitUrlCreatedDate] DESC, T.[VisitId] DESC) AS IndexRank --, T.VisitUrlId DESC
            , T.*
        FROM
            vLogVisit T
        WHERE
            T.Msisdn = @TempMsisdn
    ) AS VisitLogs
WHERE 
    IndexRank BETWEEN @RecordStartIndex AND @RecordEndIndex
ORDER BY
    VisitUrlCreatedDate DESC
  , VisitId DESC
```

I think these both approaches **take all first** and **then** **get the portion** I want.

Since the count of the data **before** taking the portion is more than 100k, is there a faster way?

Comment: Do you have indices and are those being used? I see nothing wrong with 1). Why would you do 2)?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are looking at nolock.  You just get dirty records and generally, in my experience, just causes 7105 (credit @RichardVivian) errors in my logs.  Generally shouldn't lock and messes with the optimisation plans.  What do your indexes look like?  Also - Avoid "*", rather specify the columns where you are linking against index fields.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/1662973

Comment: vLogVisit is a view which has a NOLOCK within it. So I did not write nolock again. But I forgot it by writing in the first approach :). As for "mit", I see that approach and wanted to try but the results are the same of those 2. I just wanted to show that I explored that option.

Comment: >100k rows should be no issue.  Don't underestimate the power of indexes.  We have had issue where items taking a minute to return a single record (from a few million rows) went to <1 second by just "respecting" the full index, i.e. I added another column to the join.

Comment: I see, and there are also given indexes on necessary locations. Still taking more than 20 secs. The problem I see is that the query itself taking the whole data, I am more like looking for an approach that could only get the portion without taking 'em all.

Comment: For a start, try and limit  T.* and the outer query "select *", unless there are possibilities of null values (that will influence the count(*))

Comment: Thank Anthony, but there are actually no null values. In fact, I am eliminating the most of them (there are more than 300 million data at that table) down to few 100k.

Comment: Read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/sql-server-query-slow-when-paginated